# Makefile, option to compile all "examples" in directory?

Tags: makefile, compilation, wildcard, gnu

I have seen this done in various installers, although unfortunately I cannot actually find much on how to do this or remember which programs had this feature so I can learn it from them.

I essentially am compiling a shared library (not with autoconf/libtool yet, just a standard makefile) and wish for `make test` to simply compile all files in the examples directory, linked to the library that was just built (i.e. `../bin/libfoo.so.1.0.1`)

What does the makefile format provide to do this wildcard compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're asking for a mechanism to automatically build all source files in a directory, but I dislike that approach; at some point in the future, an individual test or two will need to be disabled, and you're left doing something a little weird, like re-naming a file just so it won't automatically be compiled.

I much prefer listing every program that you intend on building in the `Makefile`, but it need not be horrible. With some [suffix rules](http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/slides/make/slides/makesuff.html) you can easily build all your `.c` files into `.o` files or directly into executables.

Here's a snippet from the AppArmor regression test suite, which is typical of what this sort of thing looks like. (I *hope* I copied out all the relevant bits, it has been a few years.)

```
SRC=access.c \
    changeprofile.c \
    changehat.c \
    changehat_fork.c \
    changehat_misc.c \
    ....
    unlink.c \
    xattrs.c

...

#only do the ioperm/iopl tests for x86 derived architectures
ifneq (,$(findstring $(shell uname -i),i386 i486 i586 i686 x86 x86_64))
SRC+=syscall_ioperm.c syscall_iopl.c
endif

...

LIBIMMUNIX:=$(shell     if [ -f /usr/lib/libapparmor.so -o -f /usr/lib64/libapparmor.so ] ; then \
                                echo -lapparmor ; \
                        elif [ -f /lib/libimmunix.so.1 -o -f /lib64/libimmunix.so ] ; then \
                                echo -limmunix ; \
                        fi )

CFLAGS+=$(CHANGEHAT_FLAGS) -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
LDLIBS+=$(LIBIMMUNIX)

EXEC=$(SRC:%.c=%)

...

all: $(EXEC) changehat.h
```

It isn't as easy as just dropping a new file into the directory; you do need to add it to the `Makefile`. But you only need to add the name, once, to one line, and it is there for good. If you want to disable it, then comment out the offending line. It's *almost* as easy and significantly more control over your build process.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now and I do appreciate the flexibility (storing old/beta tests there until they are needed or removed), I will see how it goes, thank you!